# Replace string and move part to result using Bash

Tags: string, bash, replace

```
text="TASK {5662}: Task definition"
result="TASK [5662](htttps://somelink.com/task/5662): Task definition"
```

need to "{5662}" replace with "[5662](htttps://somelink.com/task/5662)" using bash

count of task's number maybe equals or more than 4 digits

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin already tried find \{[0-9]{4,}\} as variable and replace with sed, but i have lot of same lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using bash regex and expansion features

```
text="TASK {5662}: Task definition"
re='^TASK \{([0-9]{4,})\}: Task definition$'
if [[ $text =~ $re ]]; then
    id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    result=${text/"{$id}"/"[$id](htttps://somelink.com/task/$id)"}
else
    result=
fi
```

Comment: lot of thnx!
used re='\{([0-9]{4,})\}'

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `awk` may help you on same. (where I am not hard coding the digits simply matching it by regex and putting new values then)

```
awk --re-interval -v val="[5662](htttps://somelink.com/task/5662)" 'match($0,/[0-9]{4}/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}' Input_file
```

Also `--re-interval` is for old versions of `awk` for new versions of `awk` it may not needed too.

***Solution 2nd:*** With `sed` by hard coding digits:

```
sed 's#{5662}#[5662](htttps://somelink.com/task/5662)#'  Input_file
```